# Several PendingIntent.getService for Android Wear notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, wear-os

I'm trying to make notification actions for Android Wear,

And I set an PendingIntent (.getService) for every action,

But only the first Action actually work.

My code (variables names are examples):

```
intent1 = new Intent(this, intent1.class);
Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, intent2.class);
Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, intent3.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,  intent1, 0);
pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent2, 0);
pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent3,  0);
```

Only clicking on the "pendingIntent" action, it workes.
When clicking on "pendingIntent2" or "pendingIntent3" action, they don't work.

Can you help? Thanks.

Comment: Are `intent1`, `intent2` and `intent3` really names of classes? You should name classes starting with uppercase letter. Btw. Also please post your manifest file

Comment: I just realized I really haven't added the two other services to the manifest. Thank you for making me notice.